# vee-validate 4.7 | VueJS 3 | Single input field validate

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I am using VueJS 3 and want to validate my step by step screen with single OR multiple input fields and want to check is he field valid or not and based on that I have to enable next button.
For validation I am using vee-validate plugin 4.7.3.

In my case I also do not want to use the `form` tag if possible. As my field is independent so no need to use `form`.

But as I search and read the comments of the package owner and mentioned that need to use `Form` so I used it but I just want to check the field validation as I have to show/hide the next button.

Component.vue

```
<template>
<Form :validateOnModelUpdate="true">
    <Field name="mobile" as="input" :rules="mobileRules" v-model="mobile" />
</Form>
// Want to display button if the validation match
// Out side of the form
<button class="btn btn-default" v-if="IF_VALID" > Next </button>
</template>

<script>
import * as Yup from 'yup';

export default {
    data(){
        return {
              mobile: '',
              mobileRules: Yup.string().required().min(6)
        }
     }
 }
</script>
```

If is there anyway to access the `meta` of the `Field` then may be that will be helped me.

Thanks.

I have tried to user `UseField`/`useIsFieldValid` but it shows me error that the
`field with name mobile was not found`
Also tried to use `ref` on the field but I can't able to access the meta of the Field

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using following code change:

For the field level validation need to code like this.
You can access field meta data in your component anywhere out of the `Form`

As per the owner comment if need to access this type of data out of the `component` need to achieve like this.
[Owner Comment on Discussion](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/discussions/4125#discussioncomment-4899046)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form > <!-- This is simple HTML form -->
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mobile" v-model="mobile" placeholder="000-0000-000">
            <span class="text-danger" v-if="mobileErr">{{ mobileErr }}</span>
        </form>
        <button v-if="mobileMeta.valid"> Next </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { useField } from 'vee-validate';

export default {
    setup(){
        const mobileRules =  Yup.string().required('Required').min(10, 'Must be 10 digits');
        const { meta: mobileMeta, value: mobile, errorMessage: mobileErr} = useField('mobile', mobileRules);
        return {
            mobileMeta,
            mobile,
            mobileErr
        }
    },
    data(){
        return {
            steps: '',
            loading: false
        }
    },
    created(){

    },
    methods:{
        methodOne () {
            // Some code to perform
        },
        methodTwo () {
            // Some code to perform

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Hopefully it will helps to others who want to perform step by step form and need to valid the field one by one.

Thanks.